# General Solution Differential Equation

Tags: macroeconomics, mathematical-economics, finance

We have the following system of ordinary differential equation. To solve this using diagonlsation we do the following. My concern is that my general solution is a subtly different result, I've checked with a matrix calculator and mine seems to be correct? But the subtle difference really goes on to affect the analysis I think.

1. $\frac{dX}{dt} = -cY$
2. $\frac{dY}{dt} = -cX$

$\begin{bmatrix} \frac{dX}{dt} \\ \frac{dY}{dt} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -c \\ -c & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} X \\ Y \end{bmatrix}$ Let's denote the matrix $A =\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -c \\ -c & 0 \end{bmatrix}$

$\det \begin{bmatrix} -\lambda & -c \\ -c & -\lambda \end{bmatrix} = \lambda^2 - c^2 = 0$

The eigenvalues are: $\lambda_1 = c, \quad \lambda_2 = -c$

1. $\lambda_1 = c$: $(A - cI)v_1 = 0$

$\begin{bmatrix} -c & -c \\ -c & -c \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} v_{11} \\ v_{12} \end{bmatrix} = 0$

$v_1 = \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$

2. $\lambda_2 = -c$: $(A + cI)v_2 = 0$

$\begin{bmatrix} c & -c \\ -c & c \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} v_{21} \\ v_{22} \end{bmatrix} = 0$

$v_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$

This gives me the general solution:

$X(t) = -\alpha e^{ct} + \beta e^{-ct}$

$Y(t) = \alpha e^{ct} + \beta e^{-ct}$

But what they get is

$X(t) = \alpha e^{ct} + \beta e^{-ct}$

$Y(t) = -\alpha e^{ct} + \beta e^{-ct}$

This then goes on to affect my analysis, for instance it turns out that $\alpha < 0$  therefore $-\alpha = |\alpha|$ which matters which equation it's in.

**Note:** They used substitution, and i wonder if that's how they got the different answer? But this would highlight exactly the concerns i had in a [previous post](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/55072/substitution-vs-diagonalization-for-system-of-differential-equations), regarding the different general results for the two methods, particularly in say an exam setting.

**Note:** Technically these were "Lanchester Equations" - but this seems irrelevant to the  analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in the solutions are **arbitrary constants**, true?  I suppose they are, as they are solutions of differential equations.

Therefore,  there is no difference between your solution  and their (but *they* who?)  solution, the solutions simply say that the first terms of $X(t)$ and $Y(t)$ have opposite coefficients.

$\;$

The point is **what means that letters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are *arbitrary constants*.**

What does it mean? That they vary, say in $\mathbb{R}$, **taking all possible values in $\mathbb{R}$.**

Therefore, if you write a letter, say $C$,  to mean an arbitrary value, any number you can put before it, multiplying it, doesn't change the result. That is, what you obtain is always the same, all numbers in $\mathbb{R}$.

**Example:**

- The coefficient  is $C$.  Varying $C$ in $\mathbb{R}$ you obtain all $\mathbb{R}$, obviuosly .
- the coefficient is $2C$. What do you obtain varying $C$ in $\mathbb{R}$? All $\mathbb{R}$.
- the coefficient is $- C$.  What do you obtain varying $C$ in $\mathbb{R}$? All $\mathbb{R}$.

Because, given any number c, any number in  $\mathbb{R}$, say $K$, can be obtained as solution  of $cC=K$:  you will always find a $C$ such that, given $c$, gives you $K$.

**Conclusion:** the coefficients in the solutions of the differential equations give you all real numbers, irrespective of how you write it with specific numbers.

If you write a solution of a differential equation as

$Y(t) = C e^{at} + B e^{bt}$

or

$Y(t) = 2C e^{at} - 4B e^{bt}$

it is exactly the same. The coefficients in both cases **are just all real numbers.**

So the differences are only formal, they are only 'names' for the arbitrary constants.

$\;$

**If you want the appearence of the two solutions of your problem in the question to be the same,** with the same sign in the coefficients,  just take your solution

$X(t) = -\alpha e^{ct} + \beta e^{-ct}$

$Y(t) = \alpha e^{ct} + \beta e^{-ct}$

then set $-\alpha=\gamma$ and you obtain

$X(t) = \gamma  e^{ct} + \beta e^{-ct}$

$Y(t) = -\gamma e^{ct} + \beta e^{-ct}$,

which is also formally the same as the other solution.

$\;$

> This then goes on to affect my analysis, for instance it turns out
> that $\alpha < 0$  therefore $-\alpha = |\alpha|$ which matters which
> equation it's in.

This is not clear, how can your analysis be affected?
As $\alpha$ is an arbitary constant, taking all value in $\mathbb{R}$,  what could mean that 'it turns out that $\alpha < 0$'?
It is meaningless.

The arbitrary constants can take a specific value if you addres a **further problem**, an *initial value problem* (or *Cauchy's Problem*), but this is another matter.

Comment: Thanks as always for the timely response.  So while responding to this in the post below, I think I worked out how I should think about it. The original answer sheet is attached, as well as the answer that required $-\alpha = |\alpha|$. Let me know if I got it!

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting some additional clarification to the original post here here because I don't want to confuse the original. Attached here is one the original question sheet. The context is that It's from a 2020 University Exam in Mathematical Economics, 3rd year module.

1. Original Question sheet.
2. Answer to part c) where I believe having a different general solution causes problems.

Specifically we note that if we use my answer from diagonalisation:

- $X(t) = -\alpha e^{ct} + \beta e^{-ct}$
- $Y(t) = \alpha e^{ct} + \beta e^{-ct}$

Instead of the official answer

- $X(t) = \alpha e^{ct} + \beta e^{-ct}$
- $Y(t) = -\alpha e^{ct} + \beta e^{-ct}$

Then using what's given in part c) we would get:
$\alpha + \beta > -\alpha + \beta \implies \alpha > -\alpha \implies \alpha > 0$

**Solution**

While writing this and re-reading Baker Streets answer I think I understand what I should have done now to avoid confusion.

– I should have solved my Matrix in terms of different arbitrary constants, say $c$ and $d$ and then just converted them i.e. saying $-c = \alpha$ and $d = \beta$.
– The reason I would have known that I had to do this, is that they put a specific condition on $\alpha$ and $\beta$ interns of $X(0)$ and $Y(0)$, which would indicate that the answer needs to be a specific general solutions i.e. $\alpha < 0$ so that the rest of the analysis plays out.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Sorry for reading your answer so late. As for the first part, you wrote "I think I understand what I should have done now to avoid confusion.

– I should have solved my Matrix in terms of different arbitrary constants, say 
and  and then just converted them i.e. saying −= and =. ". Yes, perfect!

Comment: No worries, thanks as always!